# On Tabhost tab click show popup

Tags: android, tabs

I need to create application that has three tabs. First tab is MapViewActivity, Second tab is Search.

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    tabHost = getTabHost();
    resources = getResources();

    AddTab(resources.getString(R.string.tab_tag1),
            R.drawable.icon_tab1, MapViewActivity.class);

    AddTab(resources.getString(R.string.tab_tag2),
            R.drawable.icon_tab2, MapViewActivity.class);

    AddTab(resources.getString(R.string.tab_tag3), R.drawable.icon_tab3,
            MapViewActivity.class);     
}

private void AddTab(String tabName, int idPhoto, Class className) {
    TabSpec tabspec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tabName);
    tabspec.setIndicator(tabName, getResources().getDrawable(idPhoto));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, className);
    tabspec.setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(tabspec);
}
```

But when someone select second tab (Search) I want to show popup inside first tab content. 
Is it possible? Do you have some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code add this

```
getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", 35).show();
            // Add pop up code here
        }
});
```

So it should loke like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

    tabHost = getTabHost();
    resources = getResources();

    AddTab(resources.getString(R.string.tab_tag1),
            R.drawable.icon_tab1, MapViewActivity.class);

    AddTab(resources.getString(R.string.tab_tag2),
            R.drawable.icon_tab2, MapViewActivity.class);

    AddTab(resources.getString(R.string.tab_tag3), R.drawable.icon_tab3,
            MapViewActivity.class);
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", 35).show();
            // Add pop up code here
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT 2:
you can use

```
getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(this);

OR

getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnClickListener(someListener);
```

Comment: There is no setOnClickListener event. I try with setOnTouchListener, but it load content of the second tab.

Comment: The set onclick was for not tab but tabwidget child, &Did you try tabchanged listener ?

Comment: It is working with setOnClickListener, but I had a problem. In your implementation you need 'new View.OnClickListener()'. Please edit, to mark as answered.